# Switch between X11 and XQuartz on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, x11, wine

Is it possible to turn off that automatic bechaviour of Mac OS X when it setting up $DISPLAY? I want to run manually X11 or XQuartz to force wine (or other X apps) using one or another. (Like it was in earler wersions of Mac OS) Because some apps works better in standart X11, but another in current version of XQuartz.

Comment: It should work to just launch whichever X server you prefer and then run wine from an xterm within it.

Comment: Thanks. Totally what i want and even better. 'cause all apps continue working with default X server. Why you comment instead answer? I'm unable to accept your answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just launch whichever X server you prefer and then run wine from an xterm within it.